# How to reduce the distance between academics and students?

Tags: teaching, university, lecture-teaching-method

While this may appear a quite open-ended question I think it is quite pertinent for a large number of subjects.

Considering undergraduate classes, particularly for students who are coming straight out of school, there is typically an expectation among students that they should not contribute to a class unless specifically asked to do so, that they are there merely to receive information, that academics are "the enemy" who can fail them, and that unless they are trying to curry favour with an academic, or attempting to gain marks that will specifically affect their GPA, that there is no reason to do any work.

This, of course, is entirely counter-productive in university. While it's clearly not within our power to change the Western schooling system that generates students that are like this, I am interested in what we can do to specifically reduce the "otherness" of academics to students within subjects that we teach: to make them realise that an academic is not an opponent that must be surmounted or avoided.

So when I say "how to reduce the distance between academics and students" I mean the psychological distance. Through this, I hope, that the actual reason for being in university might become more apparent to students, and that it might be conducive to their performing better.

This question is complicated by the fact that certain academics like and encourage this distance to reduce workloads for themselves. Disengaging from students, making it a challenge to be contacted, and maintaining an image of authority are aspects that I have seen deliberately pursued by (generally weaker) academics.

Comment: Do students really have such expectations?

Comment: You mention that "certain academics like and encourage this distance to reduce workloads for themselves." This can be resolved by administrators placing manageable workloads on academics.

Comment: @user2768 without a shadow of a doubt. Even I must admit that I wouldn't talk to an academic until I was a postgrad unless I absolutely had to. Probably meant I was missing out on tapping potentially valuable resources during my research.

Comment: @Stumber I can't relate, my experience was completely different

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but some faculty require students to come to an office hour or other appointment  once within the first month of classes in order to build a rapport. I have also seen people put up one slide per class that is a “get to know me” item. I did this once with photos of my newborn-it was actually a subtle way of getting students to understand when I was not responsive during “off” hours.

Comment: Psychological/social distance between faculty and students, and the attitude of working only for grades, are two distinct issues.

Comment: I can't relate with the description you have made for both, students and academics. Maybe this is culture related.

Comment: Can you edit this for clarification. I'm tempted, but don't want to defeat your purpose. However, all but the penultimate paragraph is extremely negative. We don't all experience this, so it is a bit rant-like. Also, you might want to say whose responsibility this is and who should act.

Comment: @Buffy well it seems a bit superfluous on a three year old, locked question!

Comment: Actually, I think the core question has merit. An edit can result in it getting reopened. The up votes suggest I'm not alone.